# How do I jump onto really high stuff in Halo?

Tags: halo-3

I've seen people on top of really high things when there's no flying vehicles. How do they get up there?

Comment: Examples please? A few different places have different methods.

Comment: Do [Warthogs count as flying vehicles](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCXpLIBCtew)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here is a list of pretty much every single jumping technique in Halo 3.](http://halowiki.net/p/Jumping)

The main one I've heard of and seen used is grenade jumping, where you throw a grenade at the ground and jump just before it detonates, boosting the player character as a result of the blast.

Answer (score 4):

Grenade or rocket jumping is how they do it.  You have to be careful and willing to take some damage depending on which version of the game you play.  It isn't very hard to do, but you do have to take some time to learn the timing.  The best way to learn it is to run a local game, load a multiplayer map and load up on rockets and grenades.  Then pick a place that has a high wall and time droping grenades onto the ground just in front of the wall.  Time the explosion and then work on jumping above the grenade just before it explodes.  You want to be just reaching the peak of your jump when the grenade goes off to boost you even higher.  You can do the same with rockets, but it has to be a bit more precise.  Practice a bit and you'll get it.

Comment: If you want to practise you can even adjust your sheilds, health, ammo etc so you can mess about to your hearts content in a custom game learning.  Still worth trying the techniques out with default settings as well to make sure a technique won't just cause you to suicide when you try it for real

Answer (score 0):

There's a fun trick for the map Relic in Halo 2. You walk over to one of those black shields found along the edge of the island that you could use for cover. Stand on the bar on the ground connected to the shield and shoot a rocket straight forward at the shield. You'll be shot up pretty far into the air. If you have trouble with it, make sure you're standing on the part where the bar makes a 'T.'

One fun thing to do is melee the shield to move it. You can do this all the way until you get close to the huge tower. Then use the trick I described and you can get all the way on top of the tower.

---

Another method that is valid for most maps that have banshees is to fly really high in the banshee, position yourself over a high platform and then jump out of the banshee and fall onto the platform.